# CKEditor breaks Angular after ng build

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a problem using a custom build of CKEditor 5 in combination with Angular 7 (7.3.9 to be specific). The editor works without a problem with ng serve, but if I try to access components containing ckeditor imports after building my Angular page via "ng build --prod" it throws either

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
```

or

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find 'BlogModule' in './component/blog/blog.module'
Error: Cannot find 'BlogModule' in './component/blog/blog.module'
```

Once I comment out the import for CKEditor and rebuild everything works as it should.
I'm using a custom build of the classic CKEditor and the docs didn't help me much as there is no documentation on how to build Angular projects with a custom CKEditor build.

The structure of my project is as follows: (reduced to the components and modules using CKEditor)

- src

  - app

    - blog

      - create-edit-post

        - create-edit-post.component.html
        - create-edit-post.component.ts
      - blog.module.ts
  - ckeditor (contains the custom build)

    - translations
    - ckeditor.js
    - ckeditor.js.map

blog.module.ts:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BlogRoutingModule } from './blog-routing.module';
import { BlogComponent } from './blog.component';
import { ViewPostComponent } from './view-post/view-post.component';
import { CreateEditPostComponent } from './create-edit-post/create-edit-post.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../material.module';
import { DeletePostComponent } from './delete-post/delete-post.component';
import { PostsComponent } from './posts/posts.component';
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CreateEditPostComponent,
    ViewPostComponent,
    BlogComponent,
    DeletePostComponent,
    PostsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    CKEditorModule,
    BlogRoutingModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    DeletePostComponent
  ]
})
export class BlogModule { }
```

create-edit-post.component.html

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;" class="user-list">
  <span style="display: flex;">
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" routerLink="/blog/posts">
      <mat-icon>arrow_back</mat-icon>
      Back
    </button>
  </span>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Title" [(ngModel)]="title" required/>
  </mat-form-field>
  <ckeditor [editor]="editor" [(ngModel)]="model.editorData" style="color: black"></ckeditor>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Tags" [(ngModel)]="tags" required/>
  </mat-form-field>
  <span style="display: flex;">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="preview()" [disabled]="!allowSave()">
      Preview
    </button>
    <span class="spacer"></span>
    <button mat-raised-button color="warn" routerLink="/blog/posts">
      Cancel
    </button>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="!allowSave()" style="margin-left: 8px;" (click)="save()">
      {{isCreate ? "Create" : "Save changes"}}
    </button>
  </span>
  <div *ngIf="showPreview" style="margin-top: 16px;">
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <mat-card style="margin-top: 16px;">
      <h2 style="margin-bottom: 4px;">{{previewTitle}}</h2>
      <sub>Created by {{previewCreator}} on {{previewCreationDate}}.</sub>
      <mat-divider style="position: relative; margin-top: 8px;"></mat-divider>
      <div class="ck-content" style="overflow: hidden;" [innerHtml]="previewContent"></div>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

create-edit-post.component.ts

```
import { AuthenticationService } from './../../../core/service/authentication/authentication.service';
import { Post } from './../../../shared/model/post';
import { BlogService } from './../../../core/service/blog/blog.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Editor from './../../../../ckeditor/ckeditor.js';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-edit-post',
  templateUrl: './create-edit-post.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-edit-post.component.scss']
})
export class CreateEditPostComponent implements OnInit {
  public editor = Editor;
  public model = {
    editorData: ''
  };

  public editorConfig = {

  };

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute,
          private blogService: BlogService, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
          private snackbar: MatSnackBar) {
this.isCreate = router.url.includes('blog/new');

if (!this.isCreate) {
  this.id = Number.parseInt(route.snapshot.params.id, 10);
  blogService.getById(this.id).subscribe(post => {
    if (!!post) {
      this.title = post.title;
      this.tags = post.tags;
      this.model.editorData = post.content;
      this.timesEdited = post.timesEdited;
    }
  });
}
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public allowSave(): boolean {
    ...
  }

  public preview() {
    ...
  }

  public save() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Angular version:

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 12.13.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.2.15
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.9
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      7.3.9
@angular/material                 7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.9
@schematics/angular               7.3.9
@schematics/update                0.13.9
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.29.0
```

I hope someone can help me fix this issue or point me into the right direction as this is the last issue that needs to be resolved before I can finish this project.

Comment: Could you show the code of the `constructor` of your component ?

Comment: I've edited my question so it shows constructor content

Comment: could be a circular dependency. find the place where you import './component/blog/blog.module'. insert const test = require('./component/blog/blog.module'') and inspect test - likely it's nothing, indicating circular dependency.

Comment: The only place where I insert blog.module is in the app.module. Also as stated in my question it's working perfectly as long as I run the page with ng build @corolla

Comment: try inserting your custom ckeditor js file inside scripts option in the build step

Comment: @deepakthomas Now it's throwing "Uncaught (in promise): CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated.". I've tried to re-install only the Angular ckeditor dependency required by ckeditor to work in Angular but it still throws the error of duplicated imports. I also checked if the editor is imported more than once in my project but only found one import (that's the one inside create-edit-post.component.ts)

Comment: Try to do `"allowJs": true,` on `tsconfig.json`  file under `"compilerOptions"`. Also, make sure that you target `ES6` or higher, Refer this https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

Comment: allowJs is set to true, switching to ES6 is a bit complicated but I followed their tutorial to enable ckeditor under ES5 @hrdkisback

Comment: Yeah for that i think you need to use `babeljs` to compile under `ES5`.

Comment: I've tried it witth babeljs but the error still appears @hrdkisback

Comment: Is that same error or different one?

Comment: It's the same error as before @hrdkisback

Comment: Could you try setting-up a reproducible example with a stackblitz of your issue ? It seems tough to test.

Comment: I think it is due of the path of the component, as it is mentioned in the error, try to delete this class and add the class by angular cli : ng g c <path>, then you will be sure to not get problem with path (you should add also to ng-modules).

Comment: @BackToReal all my components, services and modules are set up with the angular cli

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? I've been dealing with it.

Comment: No unfortunately not as there were other projects I had to work on.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to import it as documentation default method?

> import * as Editor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, I'm getting the same error as before

Comment: I think 99% the problem is this import, can we try to import in other way ckeditor?

Comment: Can you try to import it as documentation default method? import * as Editor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

Comment: Yes, the default editor does work in both development and production environments. The question is now: what did I forget to add? The docs for ckeditor in Angular aren't that helpful (or I overlooked something=

Comment: @FrancescoM. update your answer with the one in the comments so you can get your bounty

Answer (score 0):

As per CKEDitor [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html#using-a-custom-ckeditor-5-build), have you made sure to target es6 or higher? or to set `"buildOptimizer": false` in the `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment above my configuration is set to es5, but I've followed the documentation to build the custom ckeditor under es5 with the required configuration. buildOptimizer is set to false

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your routing for "BlogModule".
Go to routing area of your project. it should be 
 Error::
'BlogModule' in './component/blog/blog.module'

changae to >> "./component/blog/blog.module"

> > "module-path#moduleName"

suppose to >> "./component/blog/blog.module#BlogModule"

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it so that the necessary information and tags are provided.

Answer (score 0):

there is not  app.module.ts, set the file in src/app folder and in the imports, you're must write the proper address, like this.

```
import { BlogModule }      from './blog/blog.module';
```

as you mension

- src

  - app

    - blog

      - create-edit-post

        - create-edit-post.component.html
        - create-edit-post.component.ts
      - blog.module.ts
    - ckeditor (contains the custom build)

      - translations
      - ckeditor.js
      - ckeditor.js.map

Comment: I also mentioned that I removed all unrelated files out of the list, because only those listed are in any way using ckeditor

Comment: can i see app.module.ts,

Comment: Here you go: https://pastebin.com/68nMDbQe
BlogModule is imported in the app.routing.module.ts

Comment: witch NgModule you import blog.module.ts i want to see that NgModule

Comment: Look at my question on top, you can see the import. It's the official NgModule from Angular, but I don't know how this is in any way connected to my problem